# What are the equivalent of after and before jQuery's function in native javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I always used jQuery before, but I want to switch the following to native javascript for better performance of the website.

```
var first = $('ul li:first');
var first = $('ul li:last');

$(last).before(first);
$(first).after(last);
```

Comment: can you be more specific ?

Comment: $(last).parentNode.insertBefore(); and $(last).parentNode.insertAfter();

Answer (score 3):

From: http://clubmate.fi/append-and-prepend-elements-with-pure-javascript/

**Before** (prepend):

```js
var el = document.getElementById('thingy'),
    elChild = document.createElement('div');
elChild.innerHTML = 'Content';

// Prepend it
el.insertBefore(elChild, el.firstChild);
```

**After** (append):

```js
// Grab an element
var el = document.getElementById('thingy'),
    // Make a new div
    elChild = document.createElement('div');

// Give the new div some content
elChild.innerHTML = 'Content';

// Jug it into the parent element
el.appendChild(elChild);
```

To get the first and last `li`:

```html
var lis = document.getElementById("id-of-ul").getElementsByTagName("li"),
    first = lis[0],
    last = lis[lis.length -1];
```

if your `ul` doesn't have an id, you can always use `getElementsByTagName("ul")` and figure out its index but I would advise adding an id

Answer (score 2):

I guess you are looking for:

```
Element.insertAdjacentHTML(position, text);
```

Where `position` could be:

> `'beforebegin'`.
> Before the element itself.
>
> `'afterbegin'`.
> Just inside the element, before its first child.
>
> `'beforeend'`.
> Just inside the element, after its last child.
>
> `'afterend'`.
> After the element itself.

[image]

And `text` is a HTML string.

[Doc @ MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/insertAdjacentHTML)

Answer (score 0):

You can use `insertBefore()`:

```
var node = document.getElementById('id');
node.parentNode.insertBefore('something', node);
```

Documentation: [insertBefore()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/insertBefore)

There is no insertAfter method. It can be emulated by combining the insertBefore method with [nextSibling()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling):

```
node.parentNode.insertBefore('something', node.nextSibling);
```